# UIView with class with timer prevents deinit

Tags: swift

I am not sure if this is the best design setup, but I have something like this now:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    var nextView: NextView?

    override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
        nextView = NextView()
        nextView!.go()
    }

    deinit {
        print("call me")
    }

}

class NextView {

    var timer: Timer?

    func go() { 
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1,
                                 repeats: true,
                                 block: { [weak self] _ in })
    }

    deinit {
        print("call me")
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

With this setup, MyView and NextView wont deinitialize after the UIViewController changes from root UIViewController. If I change var nextView to weak var nextView, the deinitializers get called but nextView is nil right after the classes loads. The function go() wont be called.

How can I deinitialize both classes at the moment the UIViewController where MyView is in deinitializes, also deinits?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't simplify this too much? Everything deinits as written.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your `NextView` does not get deinitialized is because, in this setup, `MyView` holds a strong reference (and only one) to `NextView`. If you make it a `weak` reference, then `NextView` is not retained by any strong reference and is immediately deinitialized.

The way memory works in a classic UI hiearchy is the following - A view holds a strong reference to each one of its subviews, and a weak one to its superview. This prevents retain cycles while allowing the removal of a view to "cascade" the deinitialization of all its subviews.

By default, using the method `addSubview` creates this strong reference automatically, as written in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622616-addsubview).

> This method establishes a strong reference to view and sets its next responder to the receiver, which is its new superview.

So probably the good way to do it in your case, is to update your code with the following in `MyView`

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    nextView = NextView()
    addSubview(nextView)
    nextView!.go()
}
```

Hope that helps!

---

I don't want to comment too much on the code itself because that's not the topic, but I am pretty sure that creating subviews inside layoutSubviews is a terrible idea.

Also in your case, you will re-create this view each time which might be  computationally expensive. If you only want to create it once, use

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if nextView == nil {
        nextView = NextView()
        addSubview(nextView)
        nextView!.go()
    }
}
```

Comment: NextView isn't a subclass of UIView, it is just a class. The only difference is that you add it as a subview. I simplified my code to make it work, but with this setup the deinits wont be called